# return simple xml results as basic php variables

Tags: php, xml

I have a piece of code that calls an external file and returns the results from a database as an xml output as below:

```
 $file = 'http://computers.mysite.co.uk/vrm.xml?apikey=**********&vid=Check&vrm='.$reg;
  if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file))
 exit('Failed to open '.$file);
  print_r($id);
```

This returns the results like this:

```
     <computers sid="1234">
      <computer id="253406" name="computer name)" model_group="Microsofth" start_year="2005" end_year="2009">
        <system id="969623" capacity="3.4"/>
         <developer id="64" name="intel"/>
            <machine id="8" name="P" etype="P"/>
           <products>
           <product id="9" name="computer screwdriver" datasheet="" packshot=""/>
         <product id="16" name="Screwdriver Crosshead" datasheet="" packshot=""/>
       </products>
     </computer>
   </computers>
```

Instead of showing the results like this, is it possible to return them or change them into basic php variables such as:

```
   $compputer_sid
   $computer_id
   $system_id
```

and so on.

Comment: And how would you keep hierarchy ?

Comment: basic OOP variables, yes.  print_r($xml), run a `foreach` and get `$xml->computers->attributes()` and so on.

Comment: `$xml` is now an object that represents the data within the root node, and contains several methods for navigating this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Doh, you're already using SimpleXML.

you can access nodes with syntax like this:

```
$xml['sid'];//<computers sid="1234">
```

Try:

```
echo $xml['sid'];
foreach($xml->computer as $computer){
    echo $computer['id'];
    echo $computer->system['id'];
}
```

Comment: hi it now gives the following error  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 16

Comment: do a var_dump($xml) and see what it says.

Comment: ok, well it gives me a long list of variables but doesn't have the computers one, object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["sid"]=> string(4) "8696" } ["computer"] and the first one it mentions is computer

Comment: Excellent. So $xml is computers. echo $xml['sid'] and you should have your computers->sid

Comment: ok so i removed the first computers and now it works perfectly thank